# Python Pandas assign/where to compute boolean column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame and I'm trying to add some additional columns that are computed from the existing columns.  I'd like those columns to be booleans but I can't seem to get assign and where to play nice with booleans.  I'm happy to use any other type - string, or int for example - but they give me the same problem

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})

print(df)


df.assign(computed_column01=(True).where(a==1 and b==2, False))


AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'where'
```

Any guidance on the correct way to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

David

Comment: `np.where((df.A==1) & (df.B==2),True,False)`

Comment: df['computed_column01'] =  ((df.A == 1) & (df.B == 2))

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you need but you could try something like this

```
df['BOOL_both>2'] = (df.A > 2) & (df.B > 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies.  I went with

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})

df['computed_column01'] = ((df.A == 1) & (df.B == 2))

print(df)

   A  B  computed_column01
0  1  2               True
1  2  3              False
2  3  4              False
```

as suggested by Vaishali and W00lf.

interestingly I could not get the assign method to create the column.  No matter what I tried, the statement did not fail but when I print the data frame it does not contain the item...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})

df.assign(computed_column01=np.where((df.A==1) & (df.B==2), True, False))

print(df)


   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
```

I'm guessing this means I've misunderstood something...

Comment: `df.assign` returns a new dataframe with the result of the assignment. In your case you ignore the return value. To catch the assignment simply do `df=df.assign(...)`.

Comment: as simple as that - thank you - I guess i should RTFM? :)